# ¿Cómo hacer un SELECT que devuelva 3 campos diferentes? MYSQL(Cada uno con su propia condición)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que tiene 2 campos:

- Nombreyapellido
- AsistenciaOInasistencia

Necesito hacer un SELECT que me devuelta los siguientes datos:

Nombreyapellido ---   cantidadDeAsistencias ----   cantidadDeInasistencias ---  total

Imaginando que una persona puede tener varios registros, EJ:

```
Juancito 'A' (Asistencia)
Juancito 'A' (Asistencia)
Pedrito 'I' (Inasistencia)
Pedrito 'A' (Asistencia)
Juancito 'I' (Inasistencia)
```

Deseo hacer una consulta (Preferentemente con funcion COUNT()) que me devuelva el siguiente resultado:

```
Nombreyapellido --- cantidadDeAsistencias ---cantidadDeInasistencias  --- total

Juancito               2                          1                       3

Pedrito                1                          1                       2
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, por favor lee [ask]; pues ya colocaste lo que ocupas ahora por favor edita agrega que has hecho y donde tienes dudas puntuales

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarlas para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta que estás buscando es algo así:

```
SELECT *,Asistencias+Inasistencias Total FROM (
    SELECT nombre,COUNT(*) Asistencias 
      FROM asistencias WHERE asistencia='A'
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) asistencias JOIN (
    SELECT nombre,COUNT(*) Inasistencias 
      FROM asistencias WHERE asistencia='I'
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) inasistencias USING(nombre);
```

Para que podamos ayudarte con mayor facilidad, sería recomendable que modificaras la pregunta aportando el dataset en MySQL de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE asistencias(
  nombre varchar(31),
  asistencia varchar(1)
  );
INSERT INTO asistencias (nombre, asistencia) VALUES
  ('Juancito','A'),
  ('Juancito','A'),
  ('Pedrito','I'),
  ('Pedrito','A'),
  ('Juancito','I');
```

Así podremos importar los datos en un servidor MySQL y darle forma a la query para obtener lo que necesitas. En este caso he obtenido el SQL combinando dos selecciones agrupadas por nombre, una de asistencias y otra de inasistencias.

Si nos enviaras el código de tu intento, podríamos detectar qué no sabes para ayudarte a adquirir ese conocimiento. En cualquier caso, quedo a tu disposición para aclararte cualquier detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar acerca de count() [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) en ingles y [aqui](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlfun=COUNT)  en espanol. Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso se deberían evitar las subconsultas, ya que si la tabla crece mucho se puede llegar a ralentizar. MySQL Workbench tiene herramientas para poder ver el rendimiento de un consulta.

Existen otras alternativas.

En el ejemplo que adjunto he renombrado tu columna asistencia por estado para diferenciar mejor.

Para la columna asistencia evaluo con un **CASE** cuando es el "A" en ese caso vale 1 y en cualquier otro caso 0. A continuación hago un **SUM**, así sumará solo las columnas con valor "A". Para inasistencia hago la misma operación pero evaluando cuando es "I".

Para el total simplemente hago un **COUNT** de estado.

Por último se hace un **GROUP BY** por la columna que queremos hacer todas estas operaciones, en tu caso se agrupa por nombre.

```
    SELECT nombre, 
    SUM(CASE estado WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS asistencia, 
    SUM(CASE estado WHEN 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inasistencia, 
    COUNT(estado) AS total 

    FROM asistencias 

    GROUP BY nombre
```

Comment: Hola @danybarco, bienvenido a [so]. Es cierto que la solución basada en el `JOIN` de dos subconsultas tiene un `EXPLAIN PLAN` más complejo en MySQL, pero no necesariamente tiene que ser más lenta. Si defines un índice en `asistencia` calculará mucho más rápido los elementos de la selección, que contando uno a uno recorriendo cada uno de los elementos de la tabla para aplicar el `CASE`. En cualquier caso, prefiero dar soluciones con representación en álgebra relacional... :) Me alegra que haya debate, nos vemos...

Comment: @David: Sería mejor un índice compuesto, un índice sobre `asistencia` tendría una cardinalidad tan grande como inútil para el optimizador. @David, @danybarco: Al final del día, ¿No estaríamos haciendo especulaciones y -por ende- optimizaciones tempranas sobre un caso/ejemplo tan básico que de ser real ya tiene grandes problemas de diseño? La información sin contexto claro desinforma.

Comment: Pues la verdad es que sí que podría diseñarse mejor... :) Casi apetece lanzar una nueva pregunta en la que tratar esto en detalle.

Comment: Tienes razón @David, no siempre las subqueries son más costosas. Me he encontrado casos en los que optimizando índices es más rápido hacer subqueries que la solución que aporto yo. Lo malo de las subqueries para mi, es que al final se acaba abusando de ellas, quedando verdaderas monstruosidades, cuando se pueden utilizar otros recursos de SQL, que hay bastantes.